# <gtkmm/button.h>: No such file or directory Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, gtkmm, msys2

I installed with msys2 (pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkmm3) gtkmm-3.0 and I put the bin folder in the path. In codeblocks (or codelite, same result) the compiler (`pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags`) and linker (`pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs`) options.
All seems to be ok but the system doesn't find gtkmm.

here the output of `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags`

```
$  pkg-config --cflags gtkmm-3.0
-mms-bitfields -pthread -mms-bitfields -I/mingw64/include/gtkmm-3.0 -I/mingw64/lib/gtkmm-3.0/include -I/mingw64/include/atkmm-1.6 -I/mingw64/include/gdkmm-3.0 -I/mingw64/lib/gdkmm-3.0/include -I/mingw64/include/giomm-2.4 -I/mingw64/lib/giomm-2.4/include -I/mingw64/include/pangomm-1.4 -I/mingw64/lib/pangomm-1.4/include -I/mingw64/include/glibmm-2.4 -I/mingw64/lib/glibmm-2.4/include -I/mingw64/include/gtk-3.0 -I/mingw64/include/cairo -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/pango-1.0 -I/mingw64/include/fribidi -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/atk-1.0 -I/mingw64/include/cairo -I/mingw64/include/cairomm-1.0 -I/mingw64/lib/cairomm-1.0/include -I/mingw64/include/cairo -I/mingw64/include/pixman-1 -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/freetype2 -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/harfbuzz -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/include/libpng16 -I/mingw64/include/sigc++-2.0 -I/mingw64/lib/sigc++-2.0/include -I/mingw64/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/mingw64/include/libpng16 -I/mingw64/include -I/mingw64/lib/libffi-3.2.1/include -I/mingw64/include/glib-2.0 -I/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/mingw64/include
```

and here the outpu of `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --libs`

```
$  pkg-config --libs gtkmm-3.0
-L/mingw64/lib -L/mingw64/lib/../lib -L/mingw64/lib -lgtkmm-3.0 -latkmm-1.6 -lgdkmm-3.0 -lgiomm-2.4 -lpangomm-1.4 -lglibmm-2.4 -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lz -lepoxy -lopengl32 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lm -lgdi32 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lm -lpangowin32-1.0 -lm -lusp10 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -lfribidi -lthai -ldatrie -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairomm-1.0 -lcairo -lz -lpixman-1 -lm -pthread -lfontconfig -liconv -lexpat -lfreetype -lbz2 -lharfbuzz -lm -lusp10 -lgdi32 -lrpcrt4 -ldwrite -lgraphite2 -lpng16 -lz -lsigc-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lm -lgdiplus -lole32 -ljpeg -ljasper -lpng16 -lz -ltiff -lzstd -llzma -ljpeg -lz -lgio-2.0 -pthread -lintl -lshlwapi -ldnsapi -liphlpapi -lws2_32 -pthread -lgmodule-2.0 -lintl -lz -lgobject-2.0 -pthread -lintl -lffi -lintl -lglib-2.0 -lws2_32 -lole32 -lwinmm -lshlwapi -pthread -lpcre
```

can somebody help me please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Programming with all this stuff in Windows is a bad idea.

Comment: It will all work, but I recall having problems depending on which windows terminal I was using having to quote the include directories, e.g. `-I"/mingw64/include/glib-2.0" -I"/mingw64/lib/glib-2.0/include", etc...` (you may need `"c:"` at the beginning) Are you running `make` (`nmake`) or are you trying to compile with one long compiler string from the Command Prompt? I recall this being more a problem on Win7 than on Win10, but the issue is likely Win10 not resolving the `"/.../.../"` paths instead of `"c:\...\..."` type paths.

Comment: How are you building your code? The compiler doesn't use pkgconfig on its own, your build system has to feed the pkgconfig parameters to the compiler

Answer (score 0):

many thanks to

David C. Rankin 
and 
Alan Birtle,

there was an error in the compiler path and in the make command path (were in the mingw bin folder and not msys2)

now all works.